# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl (initialization failure)

Tags: java, jdbc, websphere, websphere-8, sqljdbc

I am trying to Upgrade from **sqljdbc4.jar** to  **sqljdbc4.2.jar** as JDBC driver
on **WebSphere 8.5** running on **Java 8**
but when starting my application I am getting the following exception :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl (initialization failure)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener.processAction(DialogActionListener.java:45)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewAction.broadcast(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.serviceProxied(ServletWrapper.java:307)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleFragment(CacheHook.java:562)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.CacheHook.handleServlet(CacheHook.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.cache.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PostprocessorFilter.doFilter(PostprocessorFilter.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ContainerBasedFilter.doFilter(ContainerBasedFilter.java:218)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.PreprocessorFilter.doFilter(PreprocessorFilter.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.SecurityPluginFilter.doFilter(SecurityPluginFilter.java:202)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.filenet.ae.toolkit.server.servlet.filter.ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalCleanupFilter.java:50)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at gov.mci.web.filter.CoordinatorSecurityFilter.doFilter(CoordinatorSecurityFilter.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.dataserve.common.CompatibleFilter.doFilter(CompatibleFilter.java:53)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:967)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4028)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl (initialization failure)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:91)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(DatatypeConverter.java:371)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2874)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:2361)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:44)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:2347)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1405)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1069)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:905)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:452)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:637)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.createNewConnection(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:60)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPooledConnection.<init>(SQLServerPooledConnection.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource.java:34)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper$1.run(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1365)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.getPooledConnection(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbDataSource.getPooledConnection(WSRdbDataSource.java:2154)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.getConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1802)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1572)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createManagedConnection(WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:1128)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createManagedConnectionWithMCWrapper(FreePool.java:2167)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.FreePool.createOrWaitForConnection(FreePool.java:1837)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3805)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.PoolManager.reserve(PoolManager.java:3081)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateMCWrapper(ConnectionManager.java:1548)
    at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.allocateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:644)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource.getConnection(WSJdbcDataSource.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at gov.mci.efada.entities.EntityHome.configureHibernate(EntityHome.java:54)
    at gov.mci.efada.entities.EntityHome.<init>(EntityHome.java:41)
    at gov.mci.efada.entities.EntityHome.getInstance(EntityHome.java:30)
    at gov.mci.jsf.beans.efada.Tracking.inboxQueue(Tracking.java:170)
    at gov.mci.jsf.beans.efada.Tracking.onload(Tracking.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:335)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:348)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.Error: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:907)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:356)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.setupKeyAndMac(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitFactoryImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1734)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1390)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:979)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5554)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5680)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory could not be instantiated: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:905)
    ... 44 more
```

I tried adding **jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar** and **jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar**
and I still get the same error.

**UPDATE**: when running on **sqljdbc4.jar** i didn't have to add **jaxb-api** or **jaxb-impl**
and my application was working fine, this issue only appeared when i tried to use **sqljdbc4.2.jar**.

Comment: Given the exception stack trace, you seem to have conflicting dependencies on your classpath (e.g. multiple versions of the library, possibly in different classloaders), which causes class loading errors because it tries to match implementations loaded with one version of the dependency with another version.

Comment: what is the correct jaxb implementation needed for sqljdbc4.2.jar ?
because when i used sqljdbc4.jar i didn't need any jaxb jars !

Comment: Assuming this is the SQL Server JDBC driver, have you tried using a newer version (e.g. current latest is 9.2.1). That said, the exception shown doesn't occur in that library, it occurs somewhere deep in JSF.

Comment: This exception only occurs when i use  sqljdbc4.2.jar if i rolled back to sqljdbc4.jar i get no errors at all !

Comment: That is not what I asked, I asked if upgrading to a newer version than that helped. Also, if your environment already provides JAXB, have you tried excluding the JAXB dependency from being pulled in together with that library?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for your advise, issue solved when i used a latest driver : mssql-jdbc-8.2.1.jre8.jar

Comment: can you please answer the question so that i can mark your answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is the SQL Server JDBC driver, try using a newer version (e.g. current latest is 9.2.1), and see if that resolves the problem.

Alternatively, given your application server already provides JAXB, you could also try excluding the JAXB dependency from being pulled in again through the driver.

Comment: Issue solved when i used a latest driver : mssql-jdbc-8.2.1.jre8.jar